# Error Code: 101 Missing user cookie

Tags: android, facebook-access-token, facebook-android-sdk

In my application, I'm manually setting an access token that's stored server-side.  When I try and use an FB.dialog to show an invite dialog, the web view displays "An error occured with .  Please try again later. API Error Code: 110 API Error Description: Invalid user id Error message: Missing user cookie (to validate session user)

I've verified that the token is valid, and I've been able to make requests requests with it.

Here's the implementation:

```
            Facebook facebook = new Facebook("my app id");
            try {
                facebook.setAccessToken(authToken);
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = format.parse(tokenExpiration);
                facebook.setAccessExpires(date.getTime());
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("message", "Invite Friends!");
                facebook.dialog(mActivity, "apprequests", params, new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        Log.e(e.getMessage(), e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        Log.e(e.getMessage(), e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }
                }); .....
```

No callback is made for onFacebookError or onError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, it was related to a partner's SDK messing w/ cookies.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly which sdk was messing with cookies. I am getting the same issue

Comment: this issue was with Gigya's SDK, they've got a alternative implementation of the Facebook SDK for auth that causes this conflict.

Comment: Was Gigya able to get you an updated SDK? or were you able to modify their code? I'm fighting with this as well.